# prefix-t does not display time in rxvt-unicode on Debian Jessie

Tags: linux, debian, tmux, rxvt

I'm following a tmux tutorial, and I noticed that Prefix-t does not display anything in my rxvt-unicode terminal. If I run that in an xterm, I see the current time displayed in the middle of the window.

I'm curious as to whether anyone knows why.

```
rxvt-unicode (urxvt) v9.20 - released: 2014-04-26
options: perl,xft,styles,combining,blink,iso14755,unicode3,encodings=eu+vn+jp+jp-ext+kr+zh+zh-ext,fade,transparent,tint,pixbuf,XIM,frills,selectionscrolling,wheel,slipwheel,smart-resize,cursorBlink,pointerBlank,scrollbars=plain+rxvt+NeXT+xterm
```

I'm on Debian Jessie.

Comment: works for me.  perhaps your **`TERM`** (environment) and tmux configuration are relevant.

Comment: My TERM is screen-256color, set from my .tmux.conf